# Spring ROO - To get value in java class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have created Spring ROO application using below link in Eclipse.

http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/spring-roo-fast-java-application-development-tool/

In this i am having a controller named BookController which is having @RequestMapping("/book"). This works fine but When i want to get data from textfield to java class i am not getting by moving this RequestMapping to method level.

The actionURL of page  is  = /SPringDemo/book

When i am moving this to method level like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/book")
    public String gettingData(Book book) {
        System.out.println("Book is  = " +book.getName());
       return null;
    }
```

This is not performing opeartion

Answer (score 1):

Spring web mvc try to match request with methods. This include parameters required. In your request definition you ask for a `Book` instance but, if Spring can locate any parameter or model attribute which make matching to definition, your method will not be invoked.

Check [this example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-mvc-form-annotation-config-webapp-code-example.html) which is similar to your case.

Good luck!